# Using IN query in Solr inner joins

Tags: solr, inner-join

I am using inner join in Solr and the below query works fine for me:

{!join from =_id to = relationships.collection2.key fromIndex = collection2_shard1_replica1 cache=true}_id:{!join from =_id to = relationships.collection3.key fromIndex = collection3_shard1_replica1 cache=true}name:"cloudProducts"

Now, I am trying to use IN query for name criteria, like name:("cloudProducts" OR "mobileStation" OR "standAlone"), so I make my query as:

{!join from =_id to = relationships.covered.targets.key fromIndex = app.coveredassets_shard1_replica1 cache=true}_id:{!join from =_id to = relationships.product.targets.key fromIndex = app.products_shard1_replica1 cache=true}str_extensions.tenant.lineOfBusiness.value.name:("cloudProducts" OR "mobileStation" OR "standAlone")

But it gives the parsing exception. I tried manipulating the syntax but no success. Is it possible to use IN query inside Solr inner joins? Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: If you have the default operator as OR, then you can just give the query as - name:('cloudProducts' 'mobileStation' 'standAlone'). Could you provide the details of exception

Comment: No, OR is not the default operator

Comment: "str_extensions.tenant.lineOfBusiness.value" whats is this values?... which is prefix of "name"?...which is not there in the earlier query...

Comment: "str_extensions.tenant.lineOfBusiness.value is the field name

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this problem by passing the inner query with 'v' keyword inside the inner join.

{!join from =_id to = relationships.covered.targets.key fromIndex = app.coveredassets_shard1_replica1 cache=true}_id:{!join from =_id to = relationships.product.targets.key fromIndex = app.products_shard1_replica1 cache=true v=str_extensions.tenant.lineOfBusiness.value.name:("cloudProducts" OR "mobileStation" OR "standAlone")}

OR

you can use v=$innerQuery and pass the value of inner query in Solr params.

{!join from =_id to = relationships.covered.targets.key fromIndex = app.coveredassets_shard1_replica1 cache=true}_id:{!join from =_id to = relationships.product.targets.key fromIndex = app.products_shard1_replica1 cache=true v=$innerQuery}

params:
distrib=false&innerJoinQuery1=str_extensions.tenant.lineOfBusiness.value.name:("cloudProducts" OR "mobileStation" OR "standAlone")